# How to open a new window in mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am opening a new window in pc browser using `window.open(url, '_blank')` which works perfectly. How can I do the same thing in a mobile browser? window.open seems not to be working for any of the mobile browsers. One thing that can be done is simulating `href` operation, but I also need an child window on close event in the parent window.

```
var new_window = window.open(some_url,"_blank");
var timer = setInterval(function () {
                                if (new_window.closed) {
                                    callback();
                                    clearInterval(timer);
                                }
                            }, 500);
```

Comment: Which mobile you are working on?

Comment: provide the code snipplet that you have tried

Comment: Added code snippet. @RahulTripathi Any browser in android phone.

Comment: Sometimes on mobile browsers "popup blockers" are turned on in the browser settings, since doing `window.open()` on a browser is considered a popup.

Answer (score 1):

If your `window.open` call is not a result of a click event, the browser typically treats it as a popup and blocks it. even if it didn't, mobile browser tend to have only one active tab at a time, so you can't really manipulate one window using another window.

Comment: How doe facebook do it then? If you have a facebook app integrated, in browser clicking on that will open a new window where you can login and authorise the app.

Comment: not certain about facebook...but div or dialog tags might the culprit and being styled to look like windows and being used instead of actual windows